# geopandas POLYGON coordinates to x,y coordinate columns

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe of the type:

```
 id  \
0  028f342a-b26f-4e36-b5d1-25d3428cac2f   

                                                 add  
0  POLYGON ((33.78148 3.50903, 33.12417 3.50903, ...
```

Here is the entire POLYGON:

```
;id;add
0;028f342a-b26f-4e36-b5d1-25d3428cac2f;POLYGON ((33.781475 3.5090296, 33.1241675 3.5090296, 33.1241675 4.392868066666667, 33.781475 4.392868066666667, 33.781475 3.5090296))
```

What I wish to do is to extract all `x` and `y` coordinates of the polygon corners into 2 columns. So, what I have tried is (This code is meant for the entire dataframe):

```
List_Mvv_id = list(set(df['id']))

Full =[]
for i in List_Mvv_id:
    df = df[df['id']==i]
    P = df['add'].iloc[0]
    print(P)
    for x,y in P.exterior.coords:
        df['x'] = x
        df['y'] = y

        Full.append(df)
```

However, it only returns the first coordinates of the polygon:

```
                                     id  \
0  028f342a-b26f-4e36-b5d1-25d3428cac2f   
0  028f342a-b26f-4e36-b5d1-25d3428cac2f   
0  028f342a-b26f-4e36-b5d1-25d3428cac2f   
0  028f342a-b26f-4e36-b5d1-25d3428cac2f   
0  028f342a-b26f-4e36-b5d1-25d3428cac2f   

                                                 add          x        y  
0  POLYGON ((33.78148 3.50903, 33.12417 3.50903, ...  33.781475  3.50903  
0  POLYGON ((33.78148 3.50903, 33.12417 3.50903, ...  33.781475  3.50903  
0  POLYGON ((33.78148 3.50903, 33.12417 3.50903, ...  33.781475  3.50903  
0  POLYGON ((33.78148 3.50903, 33.12417 3.50903, ...  33.781475  3.50903  
0  POLYGON ((33.78148 3.50903, 33.12417 3.50903, ...  33.781475  3.50903
```

I tried also this approach:

```
def coord_lister(geom):
    coords = list(geom.exterior.coords)
    return (coords)

coordinates_list = df.geometry.apply(coord_lister)
```

But I got stuck on extracting the x,y coordinates.

Grateful for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `apply()` to do looping it is as simple as below

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(""";id;add
0;028f342a-b26f-4e36-b5d1-25d3428cac2f;POLYGON ((33.781475 3.5090296, 33.1241675 3.5090296, 33.1241675 4.392868066666667, 33.781475 4.392868066666667, 33.781475 3.5090296))"""), sep=";")

# recreate geodataframe
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df["add"].apply(shapely.wkt.loads))

# expand the co-ordinates
gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda p: list(p.exterior.coords)).explode().apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=({0:"x", 1:"y"}))
```

|  | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 33.7815 | 3.50903 |
| 0 | 33.1242 | 3.50903 |
| 0 | 33.1242 | 4.39287 |
| 0 | 33.7815 | 4.39287 |
| 0 | 33.7815 | 3.50903 |